# Can a scope that looks up on a polymorphic be turned into an association between the two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

Suppose an `Invoice` `belongs_to` `Invoiceable`, a polymorphic, being the possible `invoiceable_type`s `Subscription`, `SubscriptioCart` and `Purchase`.

The `Invoice` table has the columns `invoiceable_type` and `invoiceable_id`. So for example, if I want to retrieve all `Invoice`s related to a `SubscriptionCart` through the polymorphic, I can do `Invoice.where(invoiceable_type: "SubscriptionCart")`.

Now how can I transform such scope into a direct association between `Invoice` and a `SubscriptionCart` through the polymorphic?

I've tried adding `belongs_to :subscription_cart` to the `Invoice` model, resulting in `@invoice.subscription_cart` returning `nil` .

This makes sense as the table `invoices` doesn't have a column `subscription_cart_id` (nor should it, as that's why we use the polymorphic).

But how do I specify what to look for in `Invoiceable` then?
I've tried `class_name: :SubscriptionCart` and `foreign_key: subscription_cart_id` but it still returns `nil`.

Stripped down models:

*Invoice model:*

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoiceable, polymorphic: true


  scope :subscription_cart, -> {
    where(invoiceable_type: "SubscriptionCart")
  }

end
```

*SubscriptionCart model:*

```
class SubscriptionCart < ApplicationRecord
    include ::Invoiceable::Subscription

    belongs_to :subscription
    has_many   :invoices, as: :invoiceable
end
```

*Subscription model:*

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
    include ::Invoiceable::Subscription

    belongs_to  :user
    has_many    :subscription_carts, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
    has_many    :invoices, as: :invoiceable, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

Invoiceable concern:

```
module Invoiceable::Subscription
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include Invoiceable

    included do
    def attributes_for_invoice_items
      {}.tap do |attributes|
        attributes["flat_fee"] = plan_invoice_item
        attributes["delivery_price"] = delivery_price_item_invoice_item if plan.deliverable?
        attributes["setup_fee"] = setup_invoice_item if setup_fee_billing_pending?
        attributes["per_unit"] = per_unit_invoice_item if base_plan.per_unit?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: First of all this looks much better. That being said not every Invoice will belong to a `SubscriptionCart` because of the polymorph. You can add the "association" to an instance via `def subscription_cart; invoiceable_type == "SubscriptionCart" ? invoiceable : nil; end` otherwise from a scope perspective you could go with `scope :subscription_carts, -> { SubscriptionCart.where(id: self.where(invoiceable_type: "SubscriptionCart").select(:invoiceable_id)))` this will return all the "invoiceable" `SubscriptionCart` objects.

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky . Is it possible to define it as an association instead of a scope or class method? Something like `belongs_to :subscription_cart` and maybe referencing the `invoiceable_type` of the polymorph? Sorry for the question but I'm new to Rails and I'm haveing a hard time understanding the polymorphism.